# Flutter Hive delete objects from query

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I want to delete objects from my hive db where the created date < 2 month ago. I have following query to select my objects:

```
Future<bool> truncatePastUserTas() async {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var twoMonthAgo = DateTime(now.year, now.month-2, now.day, now.hour).millisecondsSinceEpoch;

  var items = _userTasBox.values.where((element) => element.created < twoMonthAgo).toList();

  // here I want to delete all the returned items

  return true;
}
```

How do I delete all the items now?

Comment: How you have add or put your box items? Do they have a key or just simply use add()?

Comment: I have used await _userTasBox.add(userTas); Is there another way to add ?

Comment: you can consider using _userTasBox.put(key, userTas) and then later you can modify or delete it by the key

Comment: you may check this: https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/read_write?id=write-null-vs-delete

Comment: I though that add() would generate an integer a key automatically. Anyway I will check your answers.

Comment: I've edited your question to the previous version, as the answer should go in the answer area, not as an edit! Write your answer, and don't forget to [accept](/help/accepted-answer) it.